# Check if object exists in if statement

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check if an attribute exists in an `OR` statement, then check in an `IF` statement if it is set?

```
    @if($counsellingSession->has_session_begun == 1 || !empty($thread->close_session == 1))
         disabled
    @elseif($loop->index > 7 && $data->payment_type == 'free')
         disabled
    @endif
```

Comment: Do you sure `!empty($thread->close_session == 1)` works like you need?

Answer (score 3):

try property_exist php function if it exist it will gives you true other wise false

```
property_exist($thread,'close_session')
```

read about property_exist

http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) maybe? it will check whether the object is exists or not or null value

```
@if(isset($thread->close_session) && $thread->close_session == 1)
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

can you use `property_exists`
for example:

```
@if((property_exists($counsellingSession,"has_session_begun") && $counsellingSession->has_session_begun == 1) || (property_exists($thread,"close_session") && $thread->close_session == 1 ) )
         disabled
    @elseif($loop->index > 7 && $data->payment_type == 'free')
         disabled
    @endif
```